# Encrypt parameter in url

Tags: php

I have this url:

```
https://www.example.com/?p=user@provider.it
```

What is the best way to encrypt the email inside my URL in order to don't let user knows there is an email in the URL, something like:

```
https://www.example.com/?p=skckqbsBDoia27d
```

Obviously I will be able to decrypt `skckqbsBDoia27d` to get `user@provider.it` and `skckqbsBDoia27d` **MUST** be unique based on `email`.

The solution **MUST** works with PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Use `base64_encode()` and `base64_decode()`  accordingly.

`some@email.com` will get encoded as `c29tZUBlbWFpbC5jb20=`

```
$email = "some@email.com";
$url = "http://www.example.com?param=" . strrev(base64_encode($email));
```

Then on the receiving side:

```
echo base64_decode(strrev($_GET['param']));
```

Comment: Something more complex? I don't like users can copy `skckqbsBDoia27` and paste it in a simple base64 online decoder to get the email.

Comment: What about reversing the decoded output using `strrev()`

Comment: @aletede91 Added the string reversal so it won't be so easy. Of course if someone guesses or figures out that it's just reversed, they can still get the email.

Comment: Not bad at all. any other suggestions to add to make it more complex yet?

Comment: Just chain these as many times as you want. Double encode, reverse, whatever, just do the opposite on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about disclosing email then the best way would be to just not include the email in any form. Rather, use some other unique identifier that's associated with the user record. If it's not important that it be unguessable, you can just use the database row's pkey field `user.id` or whatever. If it needs to be unguessable, I'd create a new field like `user.public_id` with a unique constraint and then populate it with a hash or uuid.

Comment: So the email is for a person that's not a user? And the link is being sent to people other than the person who owns the email address?

Comment: There is a form with email input. User fill it and goes to the URL in the question with pre-filled email (I can't use sessions or cookies)

Comment: Ok then just encrypt with [OpenSSL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php). Don't try to reinvent the wheel.